# how to route request to cloudfront in ingress?

Tags: routes, yaml, amazon-cloudfront, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-nginx

i have a file (ingress-service.yaml) where rules regarding routing are as

```
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: server-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 5000
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

i recently deployed client service onto aws cloudfront. (https://d3qx8qdm.cloudfront.net/).

so i don't need a service to route the request to. how can i just append the request path to my cloudfront link and route to it? i tried putting host seperately for `/...` path but removing backend, service keys giving error saying these are expected.